# How reliable is the Salzburg-Budapest Railjet?

Tags: trains, weather-and-climate, event-based-effects, austria, hungary

I am thinking of going to the theatre at Budapest at 19:00, is it safe to take the 11:08-16:19 train? The 09:08-14:19 train is very expensive and I'd rather not pay more than double. Is there a statistics on the Railjets being on time? If that train doesn't go (is that a thing? I mean, flights not going happen but I am not particularly familiar with the Railjet, I have ridden it once four years ago) will my ticket be valid for the 13:08-18:19? This is in September so snow in Hungary is somewhat unlikely. The last time it snowed in the lower lands of Hungary in September was in 1936, so I will call it somewhat unlikely.

Yes, this is ridiculous but I it's a train in Hungary and I was born Hungarian (fixed now) and I have some memories of the Hungarian train system. But, it's a Railjet so I am willing to risk it.

Comment: `If that train doesn't go (is that a thing?)` Not really, no.

Comment: I have traveled from Budapest to salzburg by railjet. You will get cheaper ticket only if you book online at oebb.at and yes RJ usually on time.

Comment: Yes, see my comment below http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74258/how-reliable-is-the-salzburg-budapest-railjet?noredirect=1#comment161986_74263 I totally planned on using oebb.at.

Comment: Concerning ticket costs: I regularly travelled Salzburg-Budapest on the RJ and the cheapest way to get tickets is to buy Munich (!)-Budapest online via the Hungarian rail services (https://www.mavcsoport.hu). That's almost always cheaper than the prices offered by ÖBB. The only downside is that these tickets must be picked up at a Hungarian railway station in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have unfortunately no statistics on the Railjets being on time.
However, I have an answer to the second part of your question:  If that train doesn't go [...] will my ticket be valid for the 13:08-18:19?

If it is expected that the first train that will leave after the departure time as printed on your ticket, will arrive at least one hour after the arrival time as printed on your ticket, you have the choice between:

- Full refund for the ticket, under some conditions.
- Re-routing or continuation of your route to the final destination at the earliest opportunity, plus a compensation of 25% of the ticket price (if the delay is more than one hour but less than two hours), or a compensation of 50% of the ticket price (if the delay is more than  two hours).
- Re-routing or continuation of your route at another time at your convenience.

In this case, the second option is the most favorable for you of course.

If you book your tickets with the ÖBB or with Eurail, these terms apply. 
Note: This answer simplifies the terms. I highly recommend to read the actual terms, linked below.

Source: [Rail passengers’ rights and obligations of the Eurail group](http://www.eurailgroup.org/~/media/direct_docs/PRR.ashx), [Participating countries and companies in the Eurail group](http://www.eurailgroup.org/~/media/direct_docs/Participating%20PRR%20_1.ashx).

Comment: Yes, I was certainly looking at https://tickets.oebb.at/en/ticket because for the previous Zurich-Salzburg leg a few days prior any other website I tried to look at refused to even price it out much less sell it. Odd. Anyways, thanks for the reassurance.

Answer (score 13):

I used to be travelling a lot by railjet, and the maximum delay I got was 30 minutes, and that happened only once, altogether. (It was around when the refugees came in and rushed on the train). I took the railjet mostly from Budapest to Wien and backwards, and about twice a month from Salzburg to Budapest and back. I think it is reliable, but its mostly my own experience and I always took the one soonest after 8:30 and 15:30.

I hope you will have a good experience!

Comment: You sure you don't mean [refugees](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=568p2J5Y_7E)? (no sweat, of course.)

Comment: Indeed, refugees, thank you for putting this to my attention! I'm not a native english speaker, I meant no harm by using the word "immigrants".

Comment: While the media throws everyone in one pot, indeed many are not refugees.

Comment: The longest delay I had on this route was an hour. It happens but it's rare.